# How to traverse JSON in XSLT 3.0 when map vs array is unknown

Tags: xpath, xslt-3.0

I am working with JSON data in XSLT 3.0 for the first time and have run into issue traversing a subset of the data depending on whether it is in map or array form.

Map:

```
"book": { "id": 32, "name": "Good Book" }
```

Array:

```
"book": [{ "id": 32, "name": "Good Book" }]
```

If I know whether it will be a map or array ahead of time, I can select a value from the data like "name", but the syntax for each is different.

For map:

```
?book?name
```

For array:

```
?book?*?name
```

The problem is that in our data set, there are multiple book nodes that come in a mix of map and array form and using either of the above syntaxes will result in an error when applied to the "wrong" form.

Am I missing a version of the selection syntax that would work on both forms?

Is there a way to test whether the book node is in map vs array form before selecting? (I've tried things like castable but it doesn't seem appropriate for this case.)

I have a workaround using try/catch:

```
<xsl:try select="?book?name">
  <xsl:catch>
    <xsl:value-of select="?book?*?name"/>
  </xsl:catch>
</xsl:try>
```

But I'm wondering if there is a "better" method for solving this issue.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the type of `?book` e.g. with `if (?book instance of array(*)) then ?book?*?name else ?book?name`. The type check for a map is e.g. `?book instance of map(*)`.

Comment: Thanks Martin--I knew there had to be some way to test this!

Answer (score 2):

The best way in XSLT to deal with variable structure is through template rules. Unfortunately match patterns for maps and arrays aren't very expressive, but it's still a viable approach:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="?book" mode="process-book"/>

<xsl:template match=".[. instance of array(*)]" mode="process-book">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="?*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match=".[. instance of map(*)]" mode="process-book">
  <xsl:value-of select="?name"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael--this template rule approach is really interesting. I'm going to do some testing with this to help me understand it better. I'm marking Martin's answer as best because it fits better with how the rest of my stylesheet works--but this is very helpful.